# Using javascript OR to assert element attribute values

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatchjs (version 1.7x) to run my tests.

One of my tests is to test that an attribute contains one of a possible 2 values.

In the html below;

```
<iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/24156345/SMODAUTOMOTIVE/SMOD_Parkers/car-reviews/leaderboard-gallery/ReviewIntroduction_0" name="google_ads_iframe_/24156345/SMODAUTOMOTIVE/SMOD_Parkers/car-reviews/leaderboard-gallery/ReviewIntroduction_0" title="3rd party ad content" width="320" height="100" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" role="region" aria-label="Advertisement" tabindex="0" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-google-container-id="7" data-gtm-yt-inspected-13="true" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
```

And I need to test that if the `width` attribute is a value of `320`, then the `height` attribute can be **either** `100` **or** `200`.

So my code (snippet) is currently;

```
browser.getAttribute('#mpu-gallery iframe', 'width', function(adWidth) {
            mpuWidth = adWidth.value;
        })
        browser.getAttribute('#mpu-gallery iframe', 'height', function(adHeight) {
            mpuHeight = adHeight.value;
            if (mpuWidth = '320') {
                browser.assert.equal(mpuHeight, '100' || '200')
            }
```

But this doesn't work, and produces an error of;

`Failed [equal]: ('200' == '100') - expected "100" but got: "200"`

If the the height value is `100` then the test passes, but if the height value is `200` the test fails.

It appears that the `if` part of the code is only taking notice of the first assertion.

I also tried the following code,

```
if (mpuAdWidth = '300') {
                browser.assert.equal(mpuAdHeight, '250')
            } else if (mpuAdWidth = '300') {
                browser.assert.equal(mpuAdHeight, '600')
            }
```

but this didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You mean `if (mpuAdWidth === '300') {  browser.assert.equal(mpuAdHeight, '250') } else { browser.assert.equal(mpuAdHeight, '600') }`

Comment: I'm not familiar with nightwatch, but I would expect there to be something like `assert.contains()` which could take an array of the viable options. Might be worth checking the documentation.